# Update mysql if another field is updated

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update a field based on the value of another field, updated in the same query.

For example, this is may be my code:

```
UPDATE my_table SET qty = qty+1, complete = IF(qty = '10', '1', '0') WHERE id = '1'
```

Value of `qty` in the IF condition is the value before or after the update?

Comment: Do you really want to solve this in the same `UPDATE` query? Have you had a look at triggers?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE my_table SET qty = qty+1, complete = IF(qty = 9, '1', '0') WHERE id = '1'
```

The value in condition should be compared to value before the update, so if your condition should compare to 10 after update, so you should compare against 9 in the statement (if you increment value in comparison by one :) ).

Also, you comparing (what I guess is) numerical data to string value (in apostrophes), which causes implicit casts. You should be aware of that :)

Comment: Yes, but this is valid if the value will always increase. But the field "qty" could increase or decrease.
i could have qty = qty+4 or qty = qty-2 
The number is a variable.

Comment: @Vardar Then store the value in variable and in condition write `qty = 10 + @variable`, and in update statement `qty = qty + @variable` . That should work

Answer (score 0):

The value is after update of qty by "qty = qty+1"
So if you have qty = 5 in the table.

qty in statement "IF(qty = '10', '1', '0')", will be 6.